# How does SignalR expose it's hub methods?

Tags: c#, signalr

my datatranshub is undefined.  i'm thinking because i'm using mvc areas and my hub class sits in the area that the hub methods are not exposed correctly.  do i need to manually point my hub proxy?

```
var datatransfer = $.connection.DataTransferHub;
console.log(datatransfer);
$.connection.hub.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be automatically exposed by referencing `~/signalr/hubs` as a script in your page. That is URL is served up by the SignalR runtime and generates proxies for all the hubs exposed by the application.

If that isn't working, try hitting `~/signalr/hubs` with your browser (or Fiddler) you should get served a JavaScript file back.  If you don't then you probably have some kind of configuration issue preventing the SignalR runtime from exposing that resource.